# Merge into single row with multiple columns for dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to sample a large number of java projects from Github. I am using Google Big Query to query the GitHub archive. I am currently able to make a long list that contains every release event for the top java repos.

I would, however, like to merge results, where results with matching repo name are placed into a single row and then separate date columns for each event, preferably month by month are created with a link to the URL of the release which I will extract from the JSON payload ( there could be multiple release events in a single month). I have given a mockup below

I have little experience of SQL beyond the basics and would like to know if I am looking to do is simple or complex. I can do this all in java however I am hoping to save time by using SQL at the query stage.

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
repo.name        created at        link 

repoA   2018-12-06 02:04:27 UTC     url
repoA   2018-02-07 02:33:57 UTC     url
repoA   2018-02-18 00:55:15 UTC     url
repoB   2018-03-21 19:14:02 UTC     url
repoB   2018-04-11 02:07:04 UTC     url
repoC   2018-07-02 14:58:12 UTC     url
```

**WHAT I WANT**

```
        Jan     Feb     Mar     April   May
REPO A  URL     URL         
REPO B          URL     
REPO C          URL             URL , URL
```

**My current Query :**

*SELECT repo.name, created_at FROM githubarchive.year.2018 WHERE type = "ReleaseEvent" AND repo.name IN ( *very long list of repos* ) ORDER BY repo.name* ;

I will be adding an JSON_EXTRACT to get the payload grab the URL from the payload

SELECT repo.name, created_at, JSON_EXTRACT(payload,'$.zipball_url') FROM

SCHEMA:

```
type        STRING  NULLABLE    https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/
payload     STRING  NULLABLE    Event payload in JSON format
repo. name  STRING  NULLABLE    Repository name
created_at  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    Timestamp of associated event
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT repo.name, created_at,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) = 1 THEN link END) as jan,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) = 2 THEN link END) as feb,
       MAX(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) = 3 THEN link END) as mar
FROM githubarchive.year.2018
WHERE type = 'ReleaseEvent' AND
     repo.name IN ( very long list of repos ) 
GROUP BY BY repo.name
```